# Why does my function return an incorrect answer for the average salary question

Tags: javascript, average

I am pretty new to javascript and working on problems from leetcode.

The description included is:
"Given an array of unique integers salary where salary[i] is the salary of the employee i.

Return the average salary of employees excluding the minimum and maximum salary."

When I run my code it says that I have the incorrect output when the following array is passed in.

```
[25000,48000,57000,86000,33000,10000,42000,3000,54000,29000,79000,40000]
Expected Output: 41700.00000
My Output: 41000.00000
```

I've compared my code to other submissions and as far as I can tell mine should run the same.
Here is my code:

```js
function average(salary) {
  var sortedSalary = salary.sort();
  var total = sortedSalary.reduce((curr, acc) => {
    return curr + acc
  }, 0);
  var result = (total - sortedSalary[0] - sortedSalary[sortedSalary.length - 1]) / (sortedSalary.length - 2);
  return result;
};
console.log(average([25000,48000,57000,86000,33000,10000,42000,3000,54000,29000,79000,40000]));
```

Thank you for any insight into this.

Answer (score 4):

You're sorting the array [alphabetically](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp), not by the smallest number, so you end up removing the wrong numbers.

Use `sort((a, b) => a - b)` instead:

```js
const salary = [25000,48000,57000,86000,33000,10000,42000,3000,54000,29000,79000,40000]

function average(salary) {
  var sortedSalary = salary.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  var total = sortedSalary.reduce((curr, acc) => { return curr + acc }, 0);
  var result = (total - sortedSalary[0] - sortedSalary[sortedSalary.length - 1]) / (sortedSalary.length - 2);
  return result;
};

console.log(average(salary))
```

Comment: Note that the problem *could* have been found quite easily with basic debugging. `console.log(sortedSalary)` would have exposed the issue.

Comment: In other words, `[300, 10, 2].sort()` yields `[10, 2, 300]`

Comment: Ah, yes of course.  I'm still getting the hang of how all of the native functions work and completely forgot about that.  I utilized the debugger but just missed that whole thing completely.  Thank you everyone for the answers and the reminder to slow down and really see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const average = salary => salary
  .sort((a,b) => a - b) // sort numerically
  .filter((_,i,l) => i > 0 && i < l.length - 1) // remove first and last index
  .reduce((a,s) => a + s) / (salary.length - 2) // calculate average

console.log(average([25000,48000,57000,86000,33000,10000,42000,3000,54000,29000,79000,40000]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to be sorted at all. Apart from that, sorting is `O(N Log N)` not sufficiently efficient here. You just have to come up with an `O(N)` algorithm for this problem.

This'll pass:

```
var average = function(salary) {
    if (salary.length < 3) {
        return 0
    }

    let min = salary[0]
    let max = salary[0]
    let sum = 0

    for (let sal of salary) {
        if (sal > max) {
            max = sal
        }

        if (sal < min) {
            min = sal
        }

        sum += sal
    }

    return (sum - max - min) / (salary.length - 2)
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/average-salary-excluding-the-minimum-and-maximum-salary/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### For [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We'd like to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).
- For [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) questions, brute force algorithms usually get accepted. For interviews, brute force is less desired, especially if the question would be an [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) level, like the one you're solving.